# ModuleNotFoundError when install script with poetry

Tags: python, python-poetry

Here's what my project tree looks like

```
.
├── project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── db.py
│   └── main.py
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
```

in `main.py`

```py
from db import DB
```

in `pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
algoex = "project.main:app"
```

Here's what i've done to install

```
$ poetry install
```

**Two Questions**

1. When i run `project` from `root` dir, it `cds` into the `project dir`, is this expected?

```sh
$root> ls
project poetry.lock pyproject.toml

$root> project 
$project> ls
__init__.py db.py main.py
```

2. When I run `project` from `projectt` dir, it throws the error `ModuleNotFoundError`

```sh
$project> project
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'db'
```

Answer (score 1):

Q1: That's super weird and not expected at all. If I try to recreate this issue following your lead, I get:

```
bash: project: command not found
```

The only thing that occurs to me is that you have a `project` script that is being run instead? Perhaps try:

```
which project
```

If there are any executable `project` paths, that should show them.

Q2: You need to run the app via poetry, otherwise it doesn't inherit it's virtual env (hence the `ModuleNotFoundError`). Try this:

```
poetry run python3 project/main.py
```